# how to hide uialertview when its enter its delegate method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

hi guys I have a method called `manageui` which display a waiting view for a while and when the times out it's display `UIAlertView` which  display a message for try again
My problem is that i can't hide the `UIAlertView` before calling `manageui` called

**here is my code :**

```
    -(void)mangeui
{
    double Currenttime=0;
    double ptime=Currenttime+5000;
     NSLog(@"fire /n");

    do 
    {
        //add condition for found session
        if (Currenttime<ptime)
        {
            NSLog(@"inside if");
            [spinner setHidden:NO];
            [alert setHidden:YES];
        }
        else
        {

            alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops:(" 
                                                            message:@"No device found \n Make sure bluetooth is activated and the devices are within range." 
                                                           delegate:self 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Tap to retry"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];

         [spinner setHidden:YES];
            [alert show];

        }

        Currenttime+=1;
    } while (Currenttime < ptime+1 &&[_matchmakingClient availableServerCount]==0);
}
```

**the delegate for alertview is :**

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

{
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:true];
    [spinner setHidden:NO];

    alertView.hidden=YES;
    [self mangeui];
}
```

Comment: Follow the standard naming conventions in the code for better understandability

Comment: Hmm ? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to hide the alertview when ever i it's go to clickButtonAtindex and then call manageui is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you didn't understand the concept of delegates

here in [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) it says `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`

> The receiver is automatically dismissed after this method is invoked.

yeah there is no need to declare separately to dismiss the alert view.The method is called whenever a button in `alertview` is pressed and the `alertview` disappears

Comment: so how can i call my method inside the clickedButtonAtIndex and hide this alert

Comment: ok but it disappeared when it's finish the whole method which is in my case have while for some seconds there for the alert still on the screen I want a way to hide the alert before I call manageui function (when ever it enter it's own declaration)